# A person unaware his confidence exceeds his talent

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

So, yesterday, I got this text message from my own mother:

[image: txt from my mom asking for a word to describe "an adult whose confidence exceeds his talent, but he doesn't seem to recognize that"]

Now, after laughing for a good 5 minutes and then racking my brain for half a day, I still don't know how to help my mom insult this guy.

So, what's a good word or pithy phrase which describes:

> ***An adult whose confidence exceeds his talent, but doesn't seem to recognize that.***

?

And before you question the wisdom of helping her find such a word ... hey, the lady brought me into this world.  I owe her.

Comment: Not too far off from someone who’s too big for his boots, but not _quite_ the same thing, either.

Comment: @ermanen Thanks for the feedback. I'd prefer a shorter title. The body of the question speaks for itself, I think. I'd actually like to work the idea of my mom trying to insult someone into the title, in order to increase views and therefore # of answers, but I can't find a pithy way.

Comment: @ermanen If you really think it's setting a bad example (and Matt E. Эллен's earlier edit suggests he agrees with you), then I'll change it. Done.

Comment: In the vernacular, a standard term in my neck of the woods (UK SE) is  ***cocky little ????***, where ???? can be anything on the scale ranging from "chap/guy" thru "shit" to the c-word, depending on company. But I think the milder versions would still be frowned upon in "polite society" in the US, since Americans in general seem to think *all* usages of *cock/cocky* are based on a reference to the male member.

Comment: Dan, I was posting this answer when the OP was closed as dup, thought you might still enjoy the phrase: [**“Son, your ego is writing checks your body can’t cash!”**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRNWFtgXo2E) Stinger to Maverick, from the film *Top Gun* (1986), or with a bit more *salt* (if Mom is up to it), **"Your mouth is writing checks your ass can’t cash!"**

Comment: @LittleEva Ha! That is good!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would be an example of the [Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect):

> The Dunning–Kruger effect is a cognitive bias wherein unskilled individuals suffer from illusory superiority, mistakenly assessing their ability to be much higher than is accurate. This bias is attributed to a metacognitive inability of the unskilled to recognize their ineptitude. Conversely, highly skilled individuals tend to underestimate their relative competence, erroneously assuming that tasks that are easy for them are also easy for others.

Comment: Nice! I may have to accept this one.  But I feel like a guy with DK syndrome wouldn't actually know what DK syndrome is .. and what's the point of insulting someone if he doesn't know you're insulting him? ;)

Comment: @Dan Bron: Sometimes, the effect is more for the benefit of the bystanders - have you seen the episode of Red Dwarf where Rimmer talks about his misunderstanding of Gazpacho soup?

Comment: I haven't, but now I'm going to have to go pull up the scene in YouTube...

Comment: Just be aware that D-K is actually rather weaker than you might think, and not as simple, either. Look up the original papers. But it so perfectly expresses a well-known phenomenon that it has been widely adopted as a sort of short-hand label.

Comment: @Dan Bron: Could you please suggest some good books on etymology and obscure words. I went through some of your posts here, and you seem to be very well-versed in this area.

Comment: @user405662 I think you give me too much credit: I don’t study this stuff. I’ve just been fascinated by obscure vocabulary my whole life, so I’ve collected a little zoo full of specimens. The rest, I rely on internet research. For etymology specifically, you might want to ping Sven Yargs; he’s our resident etymologist. For obscure words, one resource I like is https://phrontistery.info .

Answer (score 2):

A sufferer of [Dunning Kruger syndrome](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dunning-Kruger%20Syndrome).